# using compressed (.gz) files with command line scripts expecting uncompressed files

Tags: linux, command-line, compression, gzip

In order to save disk space, I've gunzip-ed a lot of my files that I regularly use.  What is a best-practice way to still use the .gz version of these text files with, say, python scripts?

More specifically, is there a way to pipe the compressed file into a script that is expecting an uncompressed file?

For example, if normally I would run

```
python test.py file.txt
```

How would I run the same command with a `file.txt.gz`?

I know that I could do something like

```
gzip -dk file.txt.gz; python test.py file.txt; rm file.txt
```

But that seems a bit long winded; is there a better/faster way?

Comment: Use a process substitution: `python test.py <(zcat file.txt.gz)`

Comment: how might I use process substitution in a case where multiple gz files are involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want either

```
for file in *.txt.gz; do python test.py <(zcat "$file"); done
```

or

```
python test.py <(zcat *.txt.gz)
```

depending on how much data you want to pass to the test.py program

---

based on your comment:

```
proc_subs=$( printf ' <(zcat "%s")' *.txt.gz )
echo "python test.py $proc_subs -v"
#eval "python test.py $proc_subs -v"
```

un-comment the eval line if you like the way it looks

Comment: how would you change your second suggestion to handle the case of multiple files (per python call) as well as the python call requiring boolean flag options.  e.g. python test.py file1.txt file2.txt -v